# Tamaño de un string

Tags: c++, string

Estoy iniciando con C++, necesito conectarme a base de datos Sqlite.

He leído la pagina de la mencionada Base de datos y estoy en las ultimas pruebas para poder retornar el contenido de la consulta y es aquí donde tropiezo en el siguiente código:

```
temp = sqlite3_column_text(result, iCol);
sRetorno += static_cast<const unsigned char>(*temp);
```

La variable `std::string sRetorno;` cuando lee el contenido de `const unsigned char * temp;` solo lee el primer caracter, es decir si el contenido del campo es Hola, trae "H", y asi sucesivamente recoge de cada linea el primer caracter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate que lo que la conversión es a `unsigned char` ... has perdido el puntero, luego únicamente estás recuperando el primer caracter. El programa hace lo que se le pide pero de pura chiripa.

`std::string` no tiene un operador de asignación que acepte `unsigned char*`, este detalle unido al hecho de que lo más probable es que el valor recuperado tiene codificación ASCII (si no tendrías que usar `std::wstring`), puedes dejar la conversión a `char*`:

```
sRetorno += reinterpret_cast<const char*>(temp);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, pero al cambiar me produce el siguiente error 397 56 C:\Downloads\DevC++\Experimentos\Sqlitedb\dllmain.cpp [Error] invalid static_cast from type 'const unsigned char*' to type 'const char*'

Comment: perdón, era con *reinterpret*, dame un segundo

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora funciona perfecto!.